# JavaScript push not pushing correct values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's the code:

```
var stronglyAgree = [];
var agree = [];
var disagree = [];
var stronglyDisagree = [];
var na = [];

for (var i=0; i<survey.questions.length; i++) {

    var tempArray = [];
    tempArray[0] = i*8;
    tempArray[1] = survey.questions[i].answers[0].count;
    stronglyAgree.push(tempArray);
    console.log(tempArray);

    tempArray[1] = survey.questions[i].answers[1].count;
    agree.push(tempArray);

    tempArray[1] = survey.questions[i].answers[2].count;
    disagree.push(tempArray);

    tempArray[1] = survey.questions[i].answers[3].count;
    stronglyDisagree.push(tempArray);

    tempArray[1] = survey.questions[i].answers[4].count;
    na.push(tempArray);

}
console.log(stronglyAgree);
```

As you can see, I'm logging the `tempArray`, which is being pushed to `stronglyAgree`. When it comes to the last question, for example, I get:

```
`tempArray = [72,1]`
```

But the last array in `stronglyAgree` is `[72,0]`, which doesn't seem right to me. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign something to an array, like this

```
tempArray[1] = ...
```

you are actually mutating the array object. So, no matter how many times you mutate it, it is the same object.

And when you do,

```
stronglyAgree.push(tempArray);
...
agree.push(tempArray);
...
disagree.push(tempArray);
...
stronglyDisagree.push(tempArray);
...
na.push(tempArray);
```

You are pushing a reference to the same array object to all the other array objects. Instead, create a new array object whenever you are pushing, like this

```
stronglyAgree.push(tempArray.slice());
...
agree.push(tempArray.slice());
...
disagree.push(tempArray.slice());
...
stronglyDisagree.push(tempArray.slice());
...
na.push(tempArray.slice());
```

Now, a copy of the array is created everytime `slice` is called and the changes to `tempArray` will no more affect the arrays in the other arrays.

**Note:** The array objects created by `slice` are shallow copied arrays. So, if `tempArray` has a mutable object and if it is mutated with the `slice`d object, the changes would still be reflected in other array objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same reference and changing it:

```
var arrA = [];
var arrB = [];
var tempArray = [];
tempArray[0] = 10;
tempArray[1] = 7;
arrA.push(tempArray);
tempArray[1] = 8;
arrB.push(tempArray);
console.log(arrA); // [10,8]
console.log(arrB); // [10,8]
```

You probably would like to create a different array before you change the value.

You can use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for that or just create an array on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you push reference to tempArray not a copy. try:

```
stronglyAgree.push(tempArray.slice());
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your arrays have the same content: `tempArray`. You change `tempArray`'s content several times, but as you change it, it changes inside all of the other arrays. You need to clone `tempArray` each time before the next push so it ceases to share the values; in JavaScript, you can do it with `tempArray = tempArray.slice(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you're only creating **one** `tempArray` on each loop iteration, and modifying its contents. So all of the arrays you're pushing it on get a reference to the *same* `tempArray`, with the final set of contents you've assigned to it.

For something this simple, I wouldn't bother using `tempArray` at all:

```
for (var i=0; i<survey.questions.length; i++) {
    var i8 = i * 8;

    stronglyAgree.push([
        i8,
        survey.questions[i].answers[0].count
    ]);

    agree.push([
        i8,
        survey.questions[i].answers[1].count
    ]);

    disagree.push([
        i8,
        survey.questions[i].answers[2].count
    ]);

    stronglyDisagree.push([
        i8,
        survey.questions[i].answers[3].count
    ]);

    na.push([
        i8,
        survey.questions[i].answers[4].count
    ]);

}
```

That's if you really want to push a bunch of arrays into your `stronglyAgree` arrays and such, which seems a bit odd, especially if the first entry in all of them is `i` multiplied by 8.